# 64Bit Big Endian data from ushort array

Tags: c#, memory, endianness

I have a ushort array which holds two array items inside command.Data[]. 
I am able to combine those two item values and get 32Bit Big Endian value as UInt32 with the following picece of code.

```
UInt32 param32BitValue= (UInt32)command.Data[0] << 32 | command.Data[1];
```

I have another parameter which holds 4 items inside ushort array and I want to combine those four values into ulong value like

(Illustration)

```
UInt64 param64BitValue= (UInt64)command.Data[0] << 64 | command.Data[1] << 64 | command.Data[2] << 64 | command.Data[3];
```

Big or little endian format. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first code snippet should actually shift by 16 bits, not 32, if `command.Data` really is a `ushort[]` array.

```
uint bigEndian32 = ((uint)command.Data[0] << 16) | command.Data[1];
```

For 64-bit, you'd just keep shifting left by 16 bits more each time:

```
ulong bigEndian64 = ((ulong)command.Data[0] << 48) | (command.Data[1] << 32) | (command.Data[2] << 16) | command.Data[3];
```

Comment: This is actually very confusing, why `ushort` to hold `byte`? Still, you miss casts for this to work, e.g. `ushort << 16` will result in `0`.

Comment: @Sinatr `ushort << 16` will not return 0 as the `<<` operator applied to `ushort` returns an integer.

Comment: @Gusman, even if this is right (can't check now), `<<32` will fail.